# Bra’s, Ket’s, a Hilbert Space and its Dual.

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

So I’m trying to get this all straightened out in my head.

In Quantum mechanics we use a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ as our vector space and we say that its elements is the set of Ket’s $\left|\psi\right>$ that are our state vectors. The Bra’s $\left<\psi\right|$ are the adjoint’s of $\left|\psi\right>$. The inner product is then $\left<\psi|\psi\right>: \mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$. I’m all *fairly* comfortable with this, but please point out some errors because I’m almost positive I made some.

Now my main question. What is the dual of our Hilbert space? Is it just the bra’s? When I look up the definition of a dual space it’s says it’s the set of all linear functionals that take elements from our vector space and map it to the underlying field. So would it be accurate to say that the bra’s are not the dual space but instead the dual space is the set of all functionals $\left<\psi|\cdot \right>$ that takes elements of $\mathcal{H}$ as its argument and spits out elements of $\mathbb{C}$ because it’s an inner product?

Sorry if this is worded weird as I’m not used to rigorous mathematical definitions. Please point out my misunderstandings! Thanks!

Comment: What is the adjoint of a vector?

Comment: Probably conjugate transpose.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa yeah, I guess in physics they usually call it the hermitian conjugate, but that always confused me so I called it the adjoint (conjugate transpose) since it relates column and row vectors in linear algebra

Comment: I'm not that versed in functional analysis but if I recall correctly, you might just consider the *continuous dual*, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Duality). If you vector space is finite-dimensional this is the same as the regular dual space, but not your space is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: The dual of a Hilbert space is always isometrically (anti-)isomorphic to the Hilbert space itself. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa okay cool that’s what I thought. Now are the elements of our dual space in this case the set of Bra’s $\left<\psi\right|$ or the set of all linear functionals $\left<\psi|\cdot\right>$ that takes elements from $\mathcal{H}$ as an argument.

Comment: Aren't they the same thing? I mean, that's what the above theorem tells you. To each continuous linear functional $\left \langle \psi |\cdot\right\rangle$ corresponds a  unique vector $\left <\psi \right|$ and vice versa.